# Recommendations of a high volume log event viewer in a Java environment

Tags: java, logging

I am in a situation where I would like to accept a LOT of log events controlled by me - notably the logging agent I am preparing for slf4j - and then analyze them interactively.

I am not as such interested in a facility that presents formatted log files, but one that can accept log events as objects and allow me to sort and display on e.g. threads and timelines etc.

Chainsaw could maybe be an option but is currently not compatible with logback which I use for technical reasons.

Is there any project with stand alone viewers or embedded in an IDE which would be suitable for this kind of log handling.  I am aware that I am approaching what might be suitable for a profiler, so if there is a profiler projekt suitable for this kind of data acquisition and display where I can feed the event pipe, I would like to hear about it).

---

Update 2009-03-19:  I have found that there is not a log viewer which allows me to see what I would like (a visual display of events with coordinates determined by day and time, etc), so I have decided to create a very terse XML format derived from the log4j XMLLayout   adapted to be as readable as possible while still being valid XML-snippets, and then use the Microsoft LogParser to extract the information I need for postprocessing in other tools.

Comment: I did things like this in the past with a combination of unix tools: grep, sed, sort, uniq and used excel pivot tables and graphs for display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might implement a adapter for logback to send log4j events to a log4j receiver. This would enable you to use chainsaw. Or build an adapter which receives logback network events and exposes them for log4j.

Comment: The adapter already exists and comes with slf4j (slf4j-logj12.jar).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [splunk](http://www.splunk.com/), it doesn't do the specific things that you are looking for, but maybe it can help you achieve the end goal.

Answer (score 1):

Try [**logFaces**](http://www.moonlit-software.com), it should be helpful.

**Disclosure**: I am the author of this product.

Answer (score 1):

Given the topic of this question, I simply ***have*** to mention [Lilith](http://lilith.huxhorn.de), the log event viewer I'm developing myself.

It supports Logback access and logging events over the network (incl. a special high-performance appender implementation) and is able to import LOG4J-XML- and java.util.logging-XML-files.

Best of all, it's free, open source and I'm always curious about what features might be missing ;)

And yes, the site is crap. The app is much better, I promise :)
Just check it out.

Comment: Hi, Jörn ;-)  Lilith still shows a line per log event - I want something that can aggregate data.  Best bet right now is the Microsoft Log Parser with post processing.

Comment: If there's anything I can do to make your life easier just let me know with an email. What - exactly - are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It is an elderly question, and I want the usual stuff, i.e. not seeing every single log line, but be able to aggregate and visualize information on an ad-hoc basis..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TraceTool](http://tracetool.sourceforge.net/) (newer version [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/tracetool.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [LogLogic](http://www.loglogic.com/)

...